# Is it safe for a subroutine to write in the stack of its calling routine?

Tags: c, memory

I am currently using a routine `String_concat(char *str1, char *str2)` which, as its name suggest, concatenates two strings. To do so, this routine dynamically allocates memory on the heap (via `malloc()`). However, since the returned string is only used in the calling routine, I am thinking of directly allocating memory on the stack (via `alloca()`), hence I would replace `String_concat()` with something like `String_concat2(char* str1, char* str2, char* dest)` which would take the destination buffer (already allocated on the stack) as an argument. So my question is : Is is ok for `String_concat2()` to write in the stack of its calling routine, or must I force inlining via `__attribute__((always_inline))` ?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 2 The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address, 33) and retains
its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. 34) If an object is referred to outside of its
lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.*

Comment: And later in the project when you want to use the function to create strings that are *not* only used in the calling function, what then? This seems to be a case of premature optimization that is simply not needed nor very future-proof.

Comment: Do you want to do this for performance reasons? Because this looks like really strong coupling between the routines, and I think this is almost always a bad thing...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Dr.Nefario It's no worse than allowing `strcpy()` rather than mandating `strdup()` be used everywhere.

Comment: @EOF Since `String_concat2()` is a subroutine, its calling routine still exist, so it is ok, isn't it? (I will obviously not use the allocated String outside of the calling routine in this case)

Comment: @Dr.Nefario It is only to avoid redundancy.

Comment: @M.Timtow: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the
object is created each time.[...]*

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right, I will have to keep the old version for some cases, but in a lot of other cases it is justified.

Comment: Have you ever used `scanf`?

Comment: @Dr.Nefario In fact it is also because I am in a multi-threaded context and in a procedure of error-handling, hence I can not allow a call to malloc() to fail (it would throw the program in an inconsistent state), so I though that allocating on the stack (while knowing the size of the remaining free memory on the stack) would prevent such an problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem for a function to write in the stack frame of its calling function.

For example:

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
    *ptr = 7;
}

void bar(void) {
    int value;
    foo(&value);
}
```

In the above code, `foo` function is writing to a location which is in the stack frame of the `bar` function that calls it.

Comment: Ha obviously, Why didn't I think of it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

A callee routine can always modify values in its caller. But unless you want to use assembly language to mimic what compiler does it cannot *allocate* space in caller stack because its own variables are already there.

When you need to return an array to your caller, the only two portable ways are:

- callee allocates memory with malloc and pass that address to its caller - the caller will later free the memory block
- caller pre-allocates memory and pass a buffer to the callee - the callee only fills the buffer and does not worry where it is allocated not whether it is allocated at all (might be static or automatic storage)